# Django versioning static files at collectstatic

Tags: django, versioning, django-staticfiles

I'm looking for a way to add a version to all the static files found during a collectstatic.

The goal is to force reload of cached static file. For example if the static file source is `src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"` I want after the collectstatic to add the date to have `src="/jquery/jquery.min.js?date=2015-10-1T10:31:42"`

What is the best way to do that ?

Edit : I'm using django 1.4.2

Edit 2 : Eventually, I've updated my app to django 1.8.5

Comment: source control? What would this version do?

Comment: It's just to force the reload of cached static file. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`ManifestStaticFilesStorage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage) could help.

Comment: Could you flesh out your answer with a working example?

Comment: Ok I'm using django 1.4.2 and so I can't use ManifestStaticFilesStorage... I'll update my question with this information.

Comment: As I did not find a good solution with django 1.4.2 and given the fact that using  ManifestStaticFilesStorage is reaaaaly great, I've updated my apps to django 1.8.5 to use it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use [django-versioned-static](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-versioned-static):

> This little apps helps to manage your staticfiles when you need to minify them for production use. Moreover, it is capable of versioning the assets so that whenever you need to alter the static files, users won’t be given old file from the browser cache.

Comment: I don't like the fact that you have to configure every asset... There must be a best way to do that ! Thanks anyway !